# How do I Install Kivy for python 3.4 on my raspberry? Is that possible?

Tags: python, software-installation, shared-libraries

The question is on the title XD
How do I Install Kivy for python 3.4 on my raspberry? Is that possible?
I tried using the https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-rpi.html guide but thats only for python 2 users.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, and raised a similar question ( [Installing Kivy on Raspberry Pi 3 and making it work with Python 3.4](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66189/installing-kivy-on-raspberry-pi-3-and-making-it-work-with-python-3-4) ); I think I've found the answer ( https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/66192/65991 ), so I'll try sharing it here as well:

---

**EDIT : this MAY BREAK other software dependent on Python2, so please beware.**
**EDIT2: step 4 onwards should alleviate the possible damage from the temporary switch.**

---

I think I've managed to find a solution for this:

1. Referring to this page, set default Python to 3.4 (per-user or system-wide, according to your needs):

   > **How to change from default to alternative Python version on Debian Linux**
   >   https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux

   At this point, `python --version` should give you `Python 3.4.2`.
2. Follow instructions on the regular Kivy Install Page:

   > **User’s Guide » Installation on Raspberry Pi**
   >   https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-rpi.html
3. Test run a python script with Kivy use, using the `python` command, and see if the log shows the likes of

   ```
   [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2.dev0, git-388651a, 20170423  
   [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11)
   ```

---

**If you have changed the system-wide default Python, then do the following as well, to minimize any damage to other applications:**

4. Referring to the page in step 1, run

   > # update-alternatives --config python

   and select the python2.7 path as your default python.
5. Check that `python --version` gives you `Python 2.7.9` and that `python3 --version` gives you `Python 3.4.2` at this point.
6. Test run the script in step 3, but using `python3` instead, and check that it works as in step 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a fresh raspberry pi image with kivy preinstalled at 
http://kivypie.mitako.eu/kivy-download.html. It really saved me tons of effort and errors. Note: read the description under the download. It may state some useful info.